# Returning the amount of times a word appears in a string with a letter missing

Tags: python, string

Say I have a string `"aaatapoaaatacoaaa"` and I want to find the amount of times `"taco"` appears, but I still want to add to the total amount if the letter `"c"` was replaced with other characters, so words like `"tapo"` or `"taoo"` still count. How would I do that without any built in string searching methods like `str.find`?

I have only gotten so far:

```
def count_taco(a):
    amount = 0
    for letter in a:

count_taco("aaatapoaaatacoaaa")
```

Comment: `re.search(r'ta\wo')`

Comment: @BobDylan I suggest `len(re.findall('ta.o', s))`.

Comment: Without built in string searching methods

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm and modify it such that the third letter can be anything.

Comment: That doesnt seem to help me too much :/

Comment: '*c is missing*' ..or you mean replaced with other chars?

Comment: @Chris Why? All you have to do is slightly modify the  KMP algorithm. Read the article and do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>>> def count_taco(a):

        amount = 0
        chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        for c in chars:
            s = 'ta{}o'.format(c)
            if s in a:
                amount += a.count(s)

        return amount

>>> my_test = 'aaatapoaaatacotaooaaatacotapo'
>>> count_taco(my_test)
5 #tapo - taco - taoo - taco - tapo
```

Comment: What about the string `"tacotaco"`? You seem to assume that any "ta.o" can only appear once.

Comment: @timgeb .. thanks for the head's up...:) .. I was thinking about another question when I was writing this answer .. :P